# Illuminated USB keyboard flickers

Tags: keyboard

Does anyone know where I can download a driver for the VAKOSS TK-487-UK illuminated keyboard to run on Ubuntu? Or at least how to control the USB port so that it stops flickering on and off.

The USB port works fine but the Keyboard is not recognized by Ubuntu...

Already read the post on youtube and script but did not work either...tried changing USB ports, rebooting, etc. This has been going on for a week. The keyboard gets its power from the USB port.

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120128105854AAjgmgn

Comment: Does it comes with a USB to PS2 adapter?, try using it, via PS2...

Comment: Could be lack of power on the USB port, can you try a powered hub?

Answer (score 1):

Does the keyboard work physically? As in, do the keystrokes register? And you just have an illumination problem?

I have this keyboard and am not a touch typist, so I would fumble for the keys in the dark, looking for the scroll/light key to turn on illumination while the wife is sleeping at night.

I opened up the case and there is a red wire with a fat resistor inline running down the side, to the white backing plate, which houses the LEDs. What I did was cut this wire from the circuit board in the corner and resolder it to where the red wire of USB cable is connected to the circuit board. This effectively bypasses the logic and you have constant on of the illumination.